# SQL result addition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database with table :

- Loan
- Document
- DocumentTemplate

**Document** is having `loanId` and `documentTeplateId` as foreign key.

Every **loan** has multiple **documents**.

I want to select every loan (or `loanId`), that don't have document with `teplateId 100`.

Currently I'm stuck with this following sql:

```
SELECT l.id as loanId, d.id as documentId, d.document_templateid as documentTeplateId 
FROM loan as l
LEFT JOIN document as d ON (d.loanid = l.id)
WHERE d.document_templateid != 100
ORDER BY loanId DESC
```

It returns me something like this, obviously..

[image]

But that's not what I want.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Just select `loan id` instead of other columns.

Comment: What do you expect otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only the distinct loan ids:

```
SELECT distinct l.id as loanid
FROM loan as l
LEFT JOIN document as d
ON (d.loanid = l.id)
WHERE d.document_templateid != 100
ORDER BY loanId desc
```

Comment: use `<>` instead of `!=`

Comment: Because `<>` is defined in the ANSI 99 SQL standard and `!=` is not. So not all DB engines may support it and if you want to generate portable code then `<> ` is recommended to be used.

Comment: The OP has tagged MySQL and uses !=

Comment: It's up to you but `<>` is a standard way even in `MYSQL`. `!=` is just an alias for the standard `<>` operator.

Comment: I know what it is. I personally never use it (I just copied his code), but it is widely used and since the OP prefers this then why not.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.id as loanId
FROM loan as l
LEFT JOIN document as d
ON (d.loanid = l.id)
WHERE d.document_templateid != 100
ORDER BY loanId  DESC
GROUP BY loanId
```

"GROUP BY loanId" will group rows that have the same loanId into one row, removing the duplicates. You can only select loan.id for this to work, which fits well for your scenario since you seem to indicate this is the only value you need.

Comment: GROUP BY may have to come before ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation and a having` clause:

```
SELECT l.id as loanid
FROM loan l LEFT JOIN
     document d
     ON d.loanid = l.id
GROPU BY l.id
HAVING SUM( d.document_templateid = 100 ) = 0;
```

If you only want to consider loans that have documents, then the `JOIN` is not needed:

```
SELECT d.loanid
FROM document d
GROPU BY d.loanid
HAVING SUM( d.document_templateid = 100 ) = 0;
```